# Python Substring replacement

Tags: python, string

i need to replace the substring in the main string

```
mainstr='"Name":"xxx","age":"{"This":"has to","be":"replaced"}","dept":"cse"'
substr='"{"This":"has to","be":"replaced"}"'
```

Desired output:

```
mainstr="Name:xxx","age":"checked","dept":"cse"
```

I tried the following code:

```
for substr in mainstr:

    mainstr=mainstr.replace(substr,"checked")
    print "Output=",mainstr
```

On executing i got,

```
Output="Name:xxx","age":"{This":"has to","be":"replaced"}","dept":"cse"
```

Why the substr not getting replaced??..

Comment: Please fix the apostrophe markings in your question so it actually is a string :)

Comment: it's not strings actually. vote to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're iterating through the string, which isn't doing what you'd expect. Iterating through a string goes through each character.

All you need to do is:

```
mainstr = '"Name:xxx","age":"{This":"has to","be":"replaced"}","dept":"cse"'
substr = '{This":"has to","be":"replaced"}'
print "Output = ", mainstr.replace(substr, 'checked')
#                ^ The comma here is important.
```

NOTE: The code isn't working for you because `substr = '"{This` and not `substr = '{This"`. Notice the quotation mark at the beginning.

Comment: @harido: MAy be my mistake in rest part of the pgm.. will check it out.... thank you